# How to find a specific key in a list of dictionaries - Python/GET request response JSON

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am using Python Requests to make a GET request.
`response = requests.get(MYURL, headers = headers) data = response.json()`

In most cases, the response has an ideal structure:
Sample (ideal structure) response: https://0bin.net/paste/QyD1XU3z#2WRDIBvq+HJtS4CyNbdGL7HhU9S2sLK+ZjQpTjA-sgE

When it is structured as above, I can store a few desired values as such:
`artist_name = data[0]['artist']['artistName'] foreign_id = data[0]['artist']['foreignArtistId']`

In some cases, the response is a bit different, but still contains the data points I am after.  But, they are not always in data[0].  They could be in data[1] or some other indice.
Example of unideal structure: https://0bin.net/paste/Myc+bkQV#rYfL156jjLuqfDJGY+fj9OD4gKjJJXud5hILB61bqPC

MY QUESTION:
How can I iterate through the various indices of `data[]` to find `['artist']['artistName']` and `['artist']['foreignArtistId']`

I was thinking if I could use a variable like `d` to be an int, then use recursion to increase `d = d + 1` while searching for the two values I want, I could solve my problem.  But, this is giving me issues/immense confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The list in data contains both albums and artists, you should check to see which type of data is contained in the current iteration. If it's an artist, then you should be able to extract the name and foreign artist id.

```py
for d in data:
    if d.get("artist"):  # check for artist type
        print(d["artist"]["foreignArtistId"])
        print(d["artist"]["artistName"])
```

Comment: Thank you.  This was short and sweet.  Easy for a beginner such as myself to ingest and implement.  I am happy with the results.  Although I still have some lingering question about how to improve on what I have so far.

Comment: @ThoroughlyConfusedIndividual don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
# This function will traverse every nested dict to find your given key and it will return value of that key :)
def findkeys(node, kv):
    if isinstance(node, list):
        for i in node:
            for x in findkeys(i, kv):
               yield x
    elif isinstance(node, dict):
        if kv in node:
            yield node[kv]
        for j in node.values():
            for x in findkeys(j, kv):
                yield x


data = [{},{}, ... ]

# Iterate over list and fetch name & id from each dict if present
for obj in data:
  names = list(findkeys(obj, "artistName"))
  ids = list(findkeys(obj, "foreignArtistId"))
  if len(name)>0:
    name = names[0]

  if len(id)>0:
    id = ids[0]

  print(name, id)
```

**EASY WAY :**

```
for obj in data:
  if "artist" in obj:
    # If key is not present it will give None
    id = obj['artist'].get("foreignArtistId", None) 
    name = obj['artist'].get("artistName", None)

    print(name, id)
```

Comment: I would love to try this out, but frankly I am a bit confused on the implementation.

Comment: See, you have list of dict's right. In each dict you have [artistName, foreignArtistId] right. So you need to iterate over each dict and find whether that dict have required keys or not that is your concern.So im just iterating over each dict and finding whether that dict have [artistName, foreignArtistId] or not. so findkey will just take dict and key that you want to find, if key is present you will return value of that key in list: if there is same in nested dict you will get all values in list - you just need to take first value.

Comment: if you want simpler: you can just use if else statements in for loop

Comment: Not each Dict has artistName or foreignArtistId; some results are only albums and do not contain these keys.  Would this not throw an exception?  I suppose even if it did, i could implement try/catch (another thing I haven't learned yet).

Comment: Dont worry; I key is not present you will get None in variables,

Comment: I see.  I just found out that if you use the .get method, you will not encounter an exception (as you have stated).